# AWS Cloudwatch get names of alarms

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a javascript and I'm trying to print the names of all my alarms in AWS cloudwatch, i.e. `"jeisld-k-wialckei33k-High-CPU-Utilization, ajikh-q-m98k145k-High-Disk-Writes"` etc.

My code:

```
//configure AWS region/securities

var cw = new AWS.CloudWatch();
var alarms = cw.describeAlarms();
for (var i = 0; i < alarms.length; i ++) {
    console.log(alarms[i]);
```

However this doesn't print anything at all. Is this the correct way to get the names of all my alarms?

EDIT:
`console.log(alarms)` prints
 `[object Object]`

Comment: can you post the the results of `console.log(alarms)`

Comment: @whoacowboy see edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

[AWS CloudWatch Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatch.html#describeAlarms-property)

```
var cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();
cloudwatch.deleteAlarms(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     showAlarms(data);           // successful response
});

function showAlarms(data){
  for (var i=0; i<data.MetricAlarms.length; i++){
    console.log(data.MetricAlarms[i]. AlarmName);
  }
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can loop through the object to see how it is structured, which might give you a sense of what you are working with.

```
function showAlarms(data){
  for (var item in data) {
    console.log(item);
    for (var sub in item) {
      console.log('>:'sub);
    }
  }
}
```